# How to configure a SimpleForm input to default to no wrapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Given a custom SimpleForm input

```
class MyCustomInput < SimpleForm::Inputs::Base
  # some stuff
end
```

How can I configure this so that these inputs, by default, do not have a wrapper.

Normally I would set input-specific wrappers like this:

```
# initializers/simpleform
config.wrapper_mappings = {
  my_custom: :my_wrapper
}
```

But the following does not work, and the default SimpleForm wrapper is still applied.

```
config.wrapper_mappings = {
  my_custom: false
}
```

I'm aware that there are ways to achieve this in the view, e.g.,

```
<%= f.input :attribute, as: :my_custom, wrapper: false %>
```

or

```
<%= f.input_field :attribute %>
```

But this is not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to configure an input so that no wrapper is the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the option you already mentioned in your question, of just using `input_field` instead of `input` (more here: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#stripping-away-all-wrapper-divs), you may define your wrapper like this (untested):

```
SimpleForm.setup do |config|
  config.wrapper_mappings = {
    my_custom: :wrapper_false,
  }

  config.wrappers :wrapper_false, tag: false do |b|
    b.use :placeholder
    b.use :label_input
    b.use :hint,  wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :hint }
    b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: :span, class: :error }
  end
end
```

And then in your forms:

```
<%= f.input :attribute, as: :my_custom %>
```

More on the wrappers API: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#the-wrappers-api

**EDIT:**

After considering the case you mentioned, [I sent a PR](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/pull/1599) to `simple_form` project to allow for `wrapper: false` to be configured in `wrapper_mappings`. If it gets accepted, you should be able to disable the wrapper directly in the initializer like this:

```
config.wrapper_mappings = {
  my_custom: false
}
```

Comment: thanks @dgilerez. That makes sense - it means creating a custom wrapper for the "no wrapper" scenario. But is there really no way to assign a wrapper_mapping of false?

Comment: Never tried, but digging into the code I think it will not work: https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/form_builder.rb#L619 - if `options[:wrapper_mappings][input_type]` is defined and `false`, it will not be considered and turn to the other branch of the `if`.

Comment: To support this, I _think_ that line should be changed from `options[:wrapper_mappings][input_type]` to `!options[:wrapper_mappings][input_type].nil?`. If you open the issue on the repo, I may find some time to send a PR :P

Comment: Any luck @AndyHarvey?

Comment: thanks @dgilperez, I went with the "no-wrapper" wrapper, and works perfectly. Great job on the PR, I look forward to seeing SF adopt this soon!

Comment: Glad! Will ping you here if they do.